# If a $C^\infty$ function locally coincides with a tangent line, must the function be a line?

Tags: real-analysis

If a function locally coincides with it's tangent line, does the function have to be a line assuming it is $C^\infty$? In other words, if the function is in fact linear over some interval is it possible that it is not a line everywhere? I have a vague memory that it is possible to glue functions and retain arbitrary continuity But at the same time, if I were to consider a Taylor expansion, it seems like it would have to be a line... any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexamples exist, see non-analytic smooth functions. Something like
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x \leq 0 \\
e^{-1/x} & x > 0
\end{cases} $$
would be an example. However the function would be forced to be linear if it were required to be analytic rather than $C^{\infty}$, which I think is what you are thinking of. Analytic functions ($C^{\omega}$ functions) have to agree with Taylor expansions in a neighbourhood of each point, unlike smooth functions ($C^{\infty}$ functions) which only need to be infinitely differentiable.

Comment: Thanks, yes I had forgotten about analytic vs. $C^\infty$. To be clear from your wording, the answer would be yes if it was an analytic function, but no if it was just $C^\infty$?Your wording appeared switched in one place.

Comment: I've amended the wording